# How do we describe the molecule of Water (H2O) in English by the way of tradition/science or native/slang in the U.S.?

Tags: single-word-requests, science

I don't know how to say the water molecule in English, Just use "Water Molecule" or any other scientific description?

Comment: I've heard it called the Mickey Mouse molecule because the oxygen atom is much bigger than the hydrogen atom so the molecule looks a bit like Mickey Mouse's head under an electron microscope.

Comment: @KCH  WOW!It's really nice.This the first time I heart about the saying of water molecule!You are so kind so that I can remember the description for a long time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A molecule of water is called *a molecule of water* in English. If you want to be more scientific, you can say *a molecule of H<sub>2</sub>O*. If you want to be very scientific, you can say, *an Oxygen atom covalently bonded to two Hydrogen atoms.*

A *water molecule* is your best bet.